# SQL query on getting the users

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have a table named **users** and **user_details** I have a problem with my **user_details** table.

**users table**

***usr_id   | name***

1             | John
2             | Mary
3             | Jacob

**user_details table**

***det_id    | usr_id | seen***

1              | 1          |    0
2              | 2          |    1
3              | 3          |    0
3              | 3          |    0

this is my SQL Query

```
$sql = "SELECT *, COUNT(seen) 
    FROM user_details 
    GROUP BY usr_id 
    HAVING COUNT(seen)=0"; 

$sqlUnseen = mysqli_query($DB, $sql);

$result = mysqli_num_rows ($sqlUnseen);

echo $result;
```

I want to get the logged user's number of unseen(0) in the table
for example im logged as user **3** then the output should be **2** since user **3** in the **user_details** table has **2** zeros.

Thanks Guys.

*my output is 1 1

Comment: BTW, in `HAVING` part you can refer to aliases from `SELECT` part. So, you'd better changed `COUNT(seen)` to `COUNT(seen) AS cnt` in `SELECT` part and `COUNT(seen)` to `cnt = 0` in `HAVING` part,

Comment: '*' makes no sense in an aggregating query

Answer (score 0):

Here's the SQL statement that should work. Also, in your code you only display the number of rows returned, which isn't what you want. You want the value of the count(*) column. This also displays the resulting rows from the query in a table:

```
$sql = "SELECT a.*, 
    COUNT(seen) as cnt
    FROM users a
    JOIN user_details b
        ON a.usr_id = b.usr_id
    WHERE a.usr_id = 3
    GROUP BY a.usr_id 
    HAVING cnt = 0"; 

$sqlUnseen = mysqli_query($DB, $sql);
$allrows = mysqli_fetch_all($sqlUnseen,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows ($sqlUnseen);

echo "<p>Number of rows returned: ".$numrows."</p>\n";
if($allrows) {
    echo "<table>\n";
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach($allrows[0] as $colname => $colval) {
        echo "<td>".$colname."</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
    foreach($allrows as $recno => $row) {
        echo "<tr>\n";
        foreach($row as $colname => $colval) {
            echo "<td>".$colval."</td>\n";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    echo "</table>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, COUNT(seen) AS NumberOfUnseens FROM users us
INNER JOIN user_details ud
ON us.usr_id=ud.usr_id
WHERE ud.seen=0 AND ud.usr_id=3
GROUP BY ud.usr_id
```

Without Join

```
SELECT *, COUNT(seen) AS NumberOfUnseens FROM user_details 
WHERE seen=0 AND usr_id=3 GROUP BY usr_id;
```

Live Demo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc3f08/14

Comment: Yes it's valid you can check sqlfiddle link

Comment: In your code you are checking COUNT(seen)=0 as every recodord having count greater than one that's why you are getting Zero Records.

Comment: so what you are getting as output?